# Local only storage for larger datasets

Tags: react-native

I have a larger data set (about 5,000) colleges that I will need to occasionally have my users query on the app. It is simple as looking for the college (data entry) associated with the unique key that they have.

Originally I had this data in firebase, but got to thinking that maybe it wasn't necessary to have this require database writes/reads and it could be quicker if it all stayed device size.. as this dataset is never going to change.

Is there a go to library to do this with? I know theres react native mongo db, but I saw that was basically just built on asyncstorage, I don't know anything about async storage but I kinda assumed it wasn't built for databases with 5,000 documents.

Is there a goto with this? I was hoping no internet need would help with speed as well.

Comment: You may consider `https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage` as your local database.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, with 5000 documents i think [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) is not enought for you.

By simple you can choose [sqlite](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage), it ease to approach.

If you want a strict schema type mobile database i think [Realmjs](https://github.com/realm/realm-js) is a good solution for you.

`Realm` benefits is performance and can sync with your data from server.

But if your project side over many platforms you can choose [PouchDb](https://github.com/stockulus/pouchdb-react-native) and sync server with [CouchDb](http://couchdb.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

A combination of SQLite (react-native-sqlite-2) + PouchDB (NPMs: pouchdb-adapter-react-native-sqlite, pouchdb-react-native, pouchdb-find) + [Relational Pouch](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/relational-pouch) was perfect for me. With the help of Relational Pouch you can build a relational DB schema, which can be quite useful.

Initially, I used RealmJS -- it's a great and easy to use mobile database. But there might some potential issues like it's not supported by Expo (which is good to simplify builds, publishing, and Android/iOS normalization among other things), server-side part of Realm is available only with a subscription.